# Positional Argument Undefined

Tags: debugging, python-3.x

I am working on a larger project to write a code so the user can play Connect 4 against the computer. Right now, the user can choose whether or not to go first and the board is drawn. While truing to make sure that the user can only enter legal moves, I have run into a problem where my function legal_moves() takes 1 positional argument, and 0 are given, but I do not understand what I need to do to male everything agree.

```
#connect 4
#using my own formating

import random

#define global variables
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = "_"
TIE = "TIE"
NUM_ROWS = 6
NUM_COLS = 8

def display_instruct():
    """Display game instructions."""  
    print(
    """
    Welcome to the second greatest intellectual challenge of all time: Connect4.  
    This will be a showdown between your human brain and my silicon processor.  

    You will make your move known by entering a column number, 1 - 7.  Your move 
    (if that column isn't already filled) will move to the lowest available position.

    Prepare yourself, human.  May the Schwartz be with you! \n
    """
    )

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question,low,high):
    """Ask for a number within range."""
    #using range in Python sense-i.e., to ask for
    #a number between 1 and 7, call ask_number with low=1, high=8
    low=1
    high=NUM_COLS
    response = None
    while response not in range (low,high):
        response=int(input(question))
    return response 

def pieces():
    """Determine if player or computer goes first."""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you require the first move? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nThen take the first move.  You will need it.")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.")
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    board = []
    for x in range (NUM_COLS):
        board.append([" "]*NUM_ROWS)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    """Display game board on screen."""
    for r in range(NUM_ROWS):
        print_row(board,r)  
    print("\n")

def print_row(board, num):
    """Print specified row from current board"""
    this_row = board[num]
    print("\n\t| ", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num], "|", this_row[num],"|")
    print("\t", "|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|")

# everything works up to here!

def legal_moves(board):
    """Create list of column numbers where a player can drop piece"""
    legals = []
    if move < NUM_COLS: # make sure this is a legal column
        for r in range(NUM_ROWS):
            legals.append(board[move])
    return legals #returns a list of legal columns
    #in human_move function, move input must be in legal_moves list
    print (legals)

def human_move(board,human):
    """Get human move"""
    legals = legal_moves(board)
    print("LEGALS:", legals)
    move = None
    while move not in legals:
        move = ask_number("Which column will you move to? (1-7):", 1, NUM_COLS)
        if move not in legals:
            print("\nThat column is already full, nerdling.  Choose another.\n")
    print("Human moving to column", move)
    return move #return the column number chosen by user

def get_move_row(turn,move):
    move=ask_number("Which column would you like to drop a piece?")
    for m in range (NUM_COLS):
        place_piece(turn,move)
    display_board()

def place_piece(turn,move):
    if this_row[m[move]]==" ":
        this_row.append[m[move]]=turn


display_instruct()
computer,human=pieces()
board=new_board()
display_board(board)
move= int(input("Move?"))
legal_moves()

print ("Human:", human, "\nComputer:", computer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Right down the bottom of the script, you call:

```
move= int(input("Move?"))
legal_moves()
          # ^ no arguments
```

This does not supply the necessary `board` argument, hence the error message.